How to switch a Facebook application from development mode to live mode
I have just created, not without difficulty, a Google application to add a button to a page on my website to facilitate the login of my members. It works very well for my account because I am in development mode.
However, when I test my code on another PC with a different account, it no longer works and I get this message:
"Application inactive
This application is not accessible at the moment and the developer has been informed of the problem. You will be able to log in when the application is reactivated."
And indeed, it is in development mode, but I don't see how to switch it to live mode. I haven't found any good documentation to help me.
Could someone please help me?

Now which is it, Google, or Facebook? Assuming the latter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release

Thank youThank you for the link, that's kind.
